# to add the sum of the column as last row of a string type matrix. Also the first row is for headings and first column for names

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
  int i,j,k,grand1;
  char s1;
  char a[5][5][20];/*a 3x3 matrix of string data type*/
  clrscr();
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
      cout<<"enter value in ("<<i<<","<<j<<" )cell of first sheet ";
      gets(a[i][j]);
    }
  }
  /*value enter in the first matrix*/
  cout<<endl;

  /*display table1*/
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
      cout<<a[i][j]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
  }


  strcpy(a[5][1],"SUM");
  for(i=1;i<5;i++)
  {
    s1=0;
    for(k=0;k<4;k++)
    {
      s1=s1+int(a[i][k]); /*here it shows Lvalue error*/
    }
    a[5][i]=int(s1);
  }


  for(i=1;i<5;i++)
  {
    grand1=grand1+int(a[5][i]);
  }
  cout<<"grand sum of table1"<<grand1<<endl;
  /*here the table1 terminates*/

  getche();
}
```

the code is done.....and the error is still there please help.all the code is getting compiled and run too if only i make the errored line a comment; i.e. rest of the code is fine . The error persists in the last line only. Also since the first row is for heading and rest alll rows contain numerical values except the first column...so over all I need coumn-wise sum of last 4 rows as an element the matrix.(last row).

Comment: Do not access `a[5]` like `strcpy(a[5][1],"SUM");`, `a[5][i]=int(s1);` and  `grand1=grand1+int(a[5][i]);` because it is out-of-range.

Comment: Also note that using `gets()` from the standard library, which has unavoidable risk of buffer overrun, isn't good.

Comment: Defining `void main()` in global namespace is illegal in standard C++. You should use standard `int main()` unless you have some special reason to use non-standard declaration.

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly with indents.

Comment: Are you by chance using turbo c++?

Comment: You cannot assign values to `a[5][i]` because it is an array and what is converted from it is not a lvalue. Converting (a pointer converted from) `a[5][i]` to `int` also doesn't make sense.

Comment: yes i am using turbo c++

Comment: Are you required to use string matrix, not integer matrix?

Comment: If you can I suggest you get rid of it.  It is **way** out of date.

Comment: grand1=grand1+int(a[5][i]); if  it is out-of-range; then what must i do to get the desired results

Comment: i know it is way out of date **turbo c++** but that's what i am expected to use as per schoolnorms. :(

Comment: and no buffer overrun is detected,,,,for the gets() function